# How paint an electronic circuit?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I want to make a electronic circuit more hidden. So, I want to make it all black. The easy way is get a spray ink and use it. But will it work? Which ink or paint I can use?

Comment: I would be super wary of having to paint any circuit.  Is there any particular reason that you're wanting to do this?  And as far as I know, I can't think of any fully non-conductive paint that won't at least mess with EMI a bit.

Comment: It is a spy device. I want make it more hidden and small as possible.

Comment: Pot it in black compound or put it in really small enclosure which would have appropriate camouflage colors. Best way would be to use both.

Comment: Here's an alternative: Make the circuit part of some other circuit that has a reason to exist. I've done a tiny data logger within the PCB an industrial line driver / conditioner, with the entire data logger BOM placed *under* a DIP IC. Hiding in plain sight, nobody figures it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to make a small circuit less obvious, one way is through [potting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potting_%28electronics%29). The potting material is inert, it adds tamper-resistance and should be acceptably black for your needs.

[image: Potting a circuit]

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I added a picture. I think it illustrates the process very well.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet Nice picture!

Comment: If you use potting, take care about thermal issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to paint your circuit you probably should first apply a conformal coating.  Of course be careful with switches, mechanical devices and connectors.
And test to see that the paint is compatible with the conformal coating BEFORE you do it on a board.